# Strange "Could not deduce template argument for 'T'" error

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming, lambda

The error is in [this](http://pastebin.com/YzGMPzFz) code:

```
//myutil.h
template <class T, class predicate>
T ConditionalInput(LPSTR inputMessage, LPSTR errorMessage, predicate condition);    

//myutil.cpp
template <class T, class Pred>
T ConditionalInput(LPSTR inputMessage, LPSTR errorMessage, Pred condition)
{
        T input
        cout<< inputMessage;
        cin>> input;
        while(!condition(input))
        {
                cout<< errorMessage;
                cin>> input;
        }
        return input;
}

...

//c_main.cpp 
int row;

row = ConditionalInput("Input the row of the number to lookup, row > 0: ",
"[INPUT ERROR]: Specified number is not contained in the range [row > 0]. "
"Please type again: ", [](int x){ return x > 0; });
```

The error is:

```
Error   1       error C2783: 'T ConditionalInput(LPSTR,LPSTR,predicate)' :
could not deduce template argument for 'T' c_main.cpp        17      1
```

I've been struggling with it for hours but can't seem to find a solution. I believe mistake might be trivial, but I couldn't find anyone else encountering the error under similar circumstances.
Help much appreciated!

EDIT: Correction made by Frederik Slijkerman fixes one issue but creates another. This time the error is:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl ConditionalInput<int,class `anonymous namespace'::<lambda0> >(char *,char *,class `anonymous namespace'::<lambda0>)" (??$ConditionalInput@HV<lambda0>@?A0x109237b6@@@@YAHPAD0V<lambda0>@?A0x109237b6@@@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Please bear with me and help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ cannot deduce the return type of a function. It only works with its arguments.
You have to explicitly call `ConditionalInput<int>(...)`.

Comment: Edited, since <> needed to be replaced by lt / gt.

Comment: Correct answer in the comments of the answer above. Although this user holds the credits for it.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
row = ConditionalInput<int>(...)
```

to specify the return type explicitly.

Comment: I do not have to specify second template type?

Comment: After that I've got another error, this one giving me even greater headache. it's like this: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl ConditionalInput<int,class `anonymous namespace'::<lambda0> >(char *,char *,class `anonymous namespace'::<lambda0>)" (??$ConditionalInput@HV<lambda0>@?A0x109237b6@@@@YAHPAD0V<lambda0>@?A0x109237b6@@@Z) referenced in function _main C:\Users\CodeMaster\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Challenge8 - Pascals Triangle\Challenge8 - Pascals Triangle\c_main.obj Challenge8 - Pascals Triangle

Comment: did you put your templated function ConditionalInput in a .cpp file ?

Comment: Yes I did. And made a proper prototype in the proper header file.

Comment: Templated functions need to be put in header files, or if you want to have definition away from declaration, in a .hxx file included by the .h file.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456713/why-do-i-get-unresolved-external-symbol-errors-when-using-templates , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318915/g-duplicate-symbol-error-when-working-with-templates-noob-question/3318993#3318993 , ... for example

Comment: Thank you a bunch, that solved it! I'm giving you the correct answer since you said both things, and Fred gave the example of first correction only.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed you also need to specify the return type first if it has to be called explicitly as `Conditional<int>(...)`.

```
template <class T, class A>
T function (A) { ... }
```

whereas the following will produce compile errors:

```
template <class A, class T>
T function (A) { ... }
```